# Set overflow:hidden on react-native IOS as default

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Today react-native Android has the value overflow: hidden by default where IOS is having overflow: visible.

How do I set overflow: hidden' on IOS as well on everything within my react-native project? I dont wanna wrap every given component.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: There is no way of doing this without modifying the react native code.

On a side note, you can [try this library with UI components, react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements)